# Custom code inside Netsuite CRM like Salesforce?

Tags: crm, netsuite

I want to write a sample query inside the Netsuite CRM.

In salesforce, we can create our own visualforce pages and apex classes. The same way, is it possible to write custom code in Netsuite CRM?
I found some .js files but not able to find which file lists up the customers records.

Do anyone have idea? Please share.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If you're well acquainted with Visualforce page, Apex and Triggers in Salesforce  then probably you can think of them in Netsuite as javascript files only.  In Netsuite terminology we called them as Suitescripts (Serverside Javascript).

Below is a relative comparison view

```
Visualforce Page        :     Suitelet.js
Apex Classes (REST)     :     RESTlets.js
Triggers                :     UserEvent.js and Client.js
SOQL Query              :     Saved search / Script Search
Page layouts            :     Forms 
Visualflow              :     Workflows
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several sets of options for this in NetSuite, broadly under the name SuiteScript. I'd check out the NetSuite help documents to learn more.

Within an existing form (Eg a customer form), you could write a script which runs in the web browser and fetches further information, or even runs a query (called a saved search) and then returns the data for processing or display.

There are server-side event scripts, where the same type of code can run during or after certain record events occur.

You may also want to examine Suitelets, which are custom pages where the displayed data is completely generated by a SuiteScript

Hope this brief intro helps. Again, the online help files are your friend.

Comment: I created a new serach. It works the way I wanted at Netsuite interface. When I tried to fetch this through my code, it asked me the saved search id. I passed the internal id, but it says saved search with this id doesn't exist. Do you have any idea ? What value shall I pass ?

Comment: It wants the internal ID for the saved search. Maybe your type of saved search wasn't specified?

Comment: It is specified. Search is of type " Customer ".

Comment: If you're running a record search you need to pass something like `nlapiSearchRecord('customer',**your saved search internal id**,filters,columns);`